# Weird key values printed by ncurses

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, ascii, curses

I am doing a little program in C with the ncurses library on Linux.

I decided to check the input I received with the *getch()* function, more specifically, the *backspace* key.

The *backspace* ASCII decimal value is **127**, link: [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) 
I decided to print the numerical decimal value of the keys I pressed, for example:

a -> 97

A -> 65

] -> 93
...

The latter are correct.

However, the following values are **not** correct:

Backspace -> 7 (which is BELL)

Supr -> 74 (which is 'J')

Here is the test code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char ch;
  int column,line;
  int s_column,s_line;
  initscr();
  clear();
  noecho();
  raw();
  keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
  printw("Type: \n> ");
  refresh();
  getyx(stdscr,s_line,s_column);
  while((ch=getch())!='\n')
    {
      printw("%d",ch);
      addch(ch);
      refresh();
    }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** changing *raw()* to *cbreak()* generates the same output

Output test: (note: I type: 'a','A',(Backspace),(Supr),'J')

```
Type:
> 97a65A7^G74J74J
```

I don't understand why this is happening, can somebody explain why the Backspace key outputs 7 instead of 127, and Supr outputs 74, which is the same sa 'J'?

Comment: How is 74 both 'j' and BELL

Comment: I feel we need to see the code... And backspace may be mapped as "delete" (127) by the setup in termios.

Comment: It's worth noting that you probably need to do `keypad(stdscr, TRUE);` to allow "Special" keys through. Not sure if this is what is the problem here. The keys outside "regular" ones are also outside of the range or "char", which may affect things.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, I wrote that wrongly. It's corrected now, as well as a few other mistakes and the code and output of the program.

Comment: Some terminal types (vt100, vt220?) had their BACKSPACE key mapped to  DEL (=0x7f) Please take a look at the termcap entry for your terminal (xterm?, network?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For special function keys, `getch()` doesn't necessarily return the ASCII character, it returns one of the `KEY_xxx` codes in `<curses.h>`. In the case of Backspace, this is:

```
#define KEY_BACKSPACE   0407        /* backspace key */
```

Since you declare `ch` as `char` rather than `int`, the value `0407` is being truncated to `07`.

Change the declaration to:

```
int ch;
```

and then it will display `263` when you press Backspace.  `addch()` will still display `^G`, though, because it doesn't use the `KEY_xxx` macros. You need to handle these characters in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "special" keys are generating multi-character readings, which explains the ^ in the output.

See [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for more.

Comment: Backspace returns 7^G which is not its caret notation.

Comment: You are right, for some reason Backspace is outputting 7 and ^G, but still, why is it outputting 7? according to your link it should be '^?'